# Cmake's FetchContent with gRPC issue

Tags: cmake, grpc

I recently read the blog here: https://grpc.io/blog/cmake-improvements/ and they recommended using FetchContent as part of the Cmake configuration.

My project requires both protobuf and gRPC, and I would like to install protobuf first then gRPC. However, when there is a system that has neither installed, the proposal to use FetchCotent does not work as gRPC expects protobuf to be installed as a dependency.

How can I use FetchContent so protobuf can be installed before gRPC as part of the compilation process.

Just to be clear, the reason this doesn't work is because gRPC's make uses find_package for protobuf which requires protobuf to be installed.

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? The linked documentation states: "*If you are using CMake v3.13 or newer, you can now build & install gRPC and its dependencies in a **single step**, rather than building and installing each component separately.*"

Comment: yes but this doesnt work - it requires protobuff. when you do a fetchcontent without protobuff it fails during build because it does a find_package for protobuf and its not there. Cmake 3.17